# What is the meaning of collection attributes

Tags: plsql

I want find collection attributes in my code.
I only know about the collection object and its accessing methods.
Can anyone explain to me what "collection attributes" means?

Comment: Do not underestimate the power of self-teaching. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Collection "methods" are sometimes referred to as "attributes". Thus, the "attributes" of a collection are the methods which can be invoked on the collection:

```
Method  Type       Description
DELETE  Procedure  Deletes elements from collection.
TRIM    Procedure  Deletes elements from end of varray or nested table.
EXTEND  Procedure  Adds elements to end of varray or nested table.
EXISTS  Function   Returns TRUE if and only if specified element of varray or nested table exists.
FIRST   Function   Returns first index in collection.
LAST    Function   Returns last index in collection.
COUNT   Function   Returns number of elements in collection.
LIMIT   Function   Returns maximum number of elements that collection can have.
PRIOR   Function   Returns index that precedes specified index.
NEXT    Function   Returns index that succeeds specified index.
```

So the "accessing methods" you mention in your question are the "attributes" you're looking for.

[Documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS00508)

Unfortunately, Oracle overloads the term "attribute" but isn't really consistent in its use. For example, `%NOTFOUND` and `%ROWTYPE` are cursor attributes.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I never heard of collection methods being referred to as "attributes". Well, one learns all of his life. :-) Thanks, Bob.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to solve these questions is the official Oracle documentation. In your case it is the one about [PL/SQL Collections and Records](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS005) and for the collection methods please see [the respective chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS00508) thereof.

Comment: You have all the examples in the documentation.

Comment: type customer is table of int index by pls_integer

Comment: cust customer; then which is my attribute?

Comment: `type customer is table of int index by pls_integer;` is a declaration of a type of name `customer` which is a collection of elements of type `int` and with an index (of the collection) type of `pls_integer`. Then `cust customer` is a declaration of a variable with name `cust` which is of type `customer` defined just before. So, what attribute are you interested in ?

Comment: WHich is the attribute

Comment: None of them is. Where did you see the term "attribute"? Please post a URL of the page here.